# iOS - Possible for Safari HTML5 Web Sockets to Communicate with App on Same Device?

Tags: ios, html, websocket

Is it possible to use html5 web sockets in mobile safari to communicate with another app on the same device?  Basically, I'd like to build a socket server in a custom app and have my javascript on a page in mobile safari send messages to it via html web sockets.  I have very little experience with sockets and just thought I'd throw this idea out there.

Comment: which version are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- there is no background mode which will allow a native iOS application to "legally" keep a socket server running. The only three modes which can fully run in the background are "audio", "VoIP", and "location", and your application probably wouldn't fall into any of these categories.

Comment: how about if all i need is for the socket server to be available maybe a few minutes after the user navigates back to safari?  i don't need it to be a "Long-Running Background Task".